# Capturar fecha actual y añadirla a un registro de base de datos (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Estoy intentando añadir la **fecha** actual en cada uno de los registros que se añaden a mi base de datos para comprobar si el usuario alcanzó el número máximo de envíos por día.

Después de rellenar el formulario, envío los datos a "validate.php", donde registro todos los datos. El problema es que lo he intentado de mil formas y sigue en blanco el campo de la fecha actual (en la base de datos).

Esta es la parte de código donde tengo problema:

```
include 'conexion.php'; /*Conexión con la base de datos*/

$setDate = date('m/d/Y', time());   /*AQUÍ ES DONDE TENGO EL PROBLEMA*/

$insert = "INSERT INTO draws (setDate) VALUES ('$setDate')";

$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $insert);
```

Bueno, en realidad hay muchos más elementos, pero como decía, seguro que el problema viene de la variable. Por cierto, es importante que **solo aparezca la fecha**, para de esta forma poder filtrar los registros correctamente.

¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba:

```
include 'conexion.php'; /*Conexión con la base de datos*/

$insert = "INSERT INTO draws (setDate) VALUES (now())";

$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $insert);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ¿Si quiero guardar solo la fecha y no la hora como lo haría?